# Cron not valid?

Tags: cron, terraform, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to deploy an EventBridge rule in Terraform with the following cron expression:

```
schedule_expression = "cron (5 5 * * ? *)"
```

Trying to apply the plan however, throws

```
Error: error creating EventBridge Rule (dev-cron): 
ValidationException: Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid.
status code: 400, request id: xxx
```

I have tried a cron generator, followed AWS docs on crons, and tried different cros, all throwing the same error. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It is a small mistake, but you would want to remove the space between `cron` and the opening parenthesis.

```
schedule_expression = "cron(5 5 * * ? *)"
```

Unfortunately, AWS throws a generic error message, like `Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid`, without giving a clue what the actual error is.